# Blocking the element for UI interaction

Tags: javascript, jquery, blockui, jquery-blockui

I wanted to block the div for UI interaction while making a server side call and unblock it once the program flow returns to the client side.

If I don't include the unblock statement it goes into blocking after returning from server side process. Seems that UI blocking activates once the click function ends. So it ignores the blocking when I issue both block and unblock statements in the same function. If this is the case? Then how could I produce the desired result. (i.e. blocking the screen/element before calling some process and unblock on the flow returns)

Following is my sample code:

```
$("#button").click(function () {

        //$("#sidebar").block({
        //    message: '<h1>1Processing</h1>',
        //    css: { border: '3px solid #a00' }
        //});

        $.blockUI({
            message: '<h1>2Processing</h1>',
            css: { border: '3px solid #a00' }
        });

        var result = DoSomeServerSideProcessing();

        //$("#sidebar").unblock();
        $.unblockUI();
});
```

#### Additional Information:

The `DoSomeServerSideProcessing() uses XmlHttpRequest()` to access server side. That I would not like to change to jQuery ajax call as it is tested and matured code block and is being re-used from various points in the code.

Example code:

```
function DoSomeServerSideProcessing()
{
    var dllUrl=" ... "
    var result = httpGet(dllUrl);
}

function httpGet(theUrl) {
    var xmlHttp = null;

    xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.open('GET', theUrl, false);
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
    xmlHttp.send(null);
    var strHtml = xmlHttp.responseText;
    xmlHttp = null;

    return strHtml;
}
```

#### Update:

I tried converting the XmlHttpRequest() to $.ajax(). Still it is not blocking the UI. Code below:

(Tried both with and without beforeSend/complete handlers.

```
//$.blockUI();

//alert("before ajax call")

$.ajax({
    url: theUrl,
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "text",
    async: false,
    beforeSend: function () {
        $.blockUI();
    },
    complete: function () {
        $.unblockUI();
    },
    success: function (result) {
        strHtml = result;
        //$.unblockUI();
    }
});

//alert("after ajax call")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming

```
DoSomeServerSideProcessing()
```

is an AJAX call with a callback, and the .blockUI and .unblockUI functions are already defined somewhere else, I'd do this:

```
    function DoSomeServerSideProcessing(url,callback){
        $.post(url,function(data){
            $.unblockUI();
            callback(data);
        })
    }

    $("#button").click(function () {

        $.blockUI({
            message: '<h1>2Processing</h1>',
            css: { border: '3px solid #a00' }
        });

        var result = DoSomeServerSideProcessing(url,function(data){

        });

    });
```

Because you'd want the UnblockUI function to be called after the data is returned.

Comment: See my update in the question. I am not using $.ajax(), so how could I adjust your sample in my case? Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to put the unBlock method inside the success callback of your  `DoSomeServerSideProcessing` ajax call.

AJAX is asynchronous so while it is exchanging data with server the remainder of your code will run

Comment: need to update your request with onreadystatechange callback. Simpler to just switch to jQuery

Comment: OK. I tried converting the XmlHttpRequest to $.ajax(). Please see my code in the update above.

Comment: :(. I have injected the jquery.blockUI.js dynamically in the page. Will this matter?

Comment: define `inject dynamically`. If the code is valid at browser doesn't matter how it gets in the page

Comment: I meant like this: document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(scriptBlockUiJs);

Comment: Now I have noticed some strange behavior. When I call the $.blockUI() from  $("#dial").click (independent of any ajax call) it blocks the UI. But when I call the blockUI from the httpGet() method that is nested 2 levels inside the $("#dial").click it returns error in the firebug console: $.blockUI is not a function

Comment: is jQuery library being loaded more than once?

Comment: Yes, but two different versions. Actually I am working inside 3rd party web application that has already used some older version of jQuery. And for my purpose I have added the latest one. Could it create a problem?

Comment: Regarding my 2nd last comment ("Now I have noticed ...."). That was due to jQuery.BlockUI was not being loaded on some particular pages due to conditional flow. Well, after correcting the same, still the blockui is not working. No error in console this time.

Comment: Still the issue is same. If I comment out the unblock statement from `complete` handler it goes into blocking after returning from ajax call.

Comment: yes , loading 2 versions of jQuery can cause lots of problems if not done properly

Comment: Well, I managed to convert my jQuery code on the older version of jQuery that was already included in the web application. Now only one version of jQuery is included in the page. Still the issue is same. BlockUI doesn't take effect while having UnblockUI called in the `complete` handler of $.ajax(). And goes into blocking indefinitely if UnblockUI commented out. I guess it might be due to lot of script files already included by the application vendor that is somehow conflicting with the BlockUI plugin. Could it be the case?

Comment: No. But it seems I have traced the issue now. That is when I comment out the `async: false` the Block/Unblock logic works as expected. But the ajax returned data is not passed on to the calling function. :)

Comment: never use `async: false`, consume data in ajax success callback

Comment: BlockUI worked with calling Ajax asynchronously but due to async nature of the call the data returned from server side was not being passed on to the calling function. WICS2 suggested way of using callback (in his answer below) helped great to control the scenario. It is working well now.